# How write a property test for particular list content

Tags: scala, scalacheck, property-testing

I have following function, that I want to test it with ScalaCheck:

```
object Windows {

  val Directory = "^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\(((?![<>:\"/\\\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])\\\\)?)*$".r


  def arePathsValid(paths: List[String]): Eval[List[String]] = {
    Foldable[List]
      .foldRight(paths, Eval.later(List.empty[String]))((a: String, b: Eval[List[String]]) => {
        Directory.findFirstIn(a) match {
          case Some(a) => b.map(a :: _)
          case None => b
        }
      })
  }
}
```

I tried to start with:

```
val propPaths = forAll { l: List[String] => ??? }
```

But could not write the implementation for the property.

The `String`, that should be random generated in the `List`, should has a Windows pattern path, for example:

```
C:\temp\foo
```

How to do the property implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Windows path prefix like this:

```
val strGen = Gen.alphaStr // Or any other String generator
val windowsPathGen = strGen.map("C:\temp\foo" + _)
```

Comment: How to pass the created `Generator` to properties, for example `forAll`?

Comment: You can create property like this: 
property("check") = forAll(windowsPathGen) {
    item => item.startsWith("C:\temp\foo")
}